# Read csv from specific row

Tags: r

I have daily data starting from 1980 in csv file. But I want to read data only from 1985. Because the other dataset in another file starts from 1985. How can I skip reading the data before 1985 in R language?

Answer (score 34):

I think you want to take a look at [`?read.csv`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html) to see all the options.

It's a bit hard to give an exact answer without seeing a sample of your data.

If your data doesn't have a header and you know which line the 1985 data starts on, you can just use something like...

```
impordata <- read.csv(file,skip=1825)
```

...to skip the first 1825 lines.

Otherwise you can always just subset the data after you've imported it if you have a year variable in your data.

```
impordata <- read.csv("skiplines.csv")
impordata <- subset(impordata,year>=1985)
```

If you don't know where the 1985 data starts, you can use grep to find the first instance of 1985 in your file's date variable and then only keep from that line onwards:

```
impordata <- read.csv("skiplines.csv")
impordata <- impordata[min(grep(1985,impordata$date)):nrow(impordata),]
```

Answer (score 20):

Here are a few alternatives.  (You may wish to convert the first column to `"Date"` class afterwards and possibly convert the entire thing to a zoo object or other time series class object.)

```
# create test data
fn <- tempfile()
dd <- seq(as.Date("1980-01-01"), as.Date("1989-12-31"), by = "day")
DF <- data.frame(Date = dd, Value = seq_along(dd))
write.table(DF, file = fn, row.names = FALSE)
```

**read.table + subset**

```
# if file is small enough to fit in memory try this:

DF2 <- read.table(fn, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
DF2 <- subset(DF2, Date >= "1985-01-01")
```

**read.zoo**

```
# or this which produces a zoo object and also automatically converts the 
# Date column to Date class.  Note that all columns other than the Date column
# should be numeric for it to be representable as a zoo object.
library(zoo)
z <- read.zoo(fn, header = TRUE)
zw <- window(z, start = "1985-01-01")
```

If your data is not in the same format as the example you will need to use additional arguments to `read.zoo`.

**multiple read.table's**

```
# if the data is very large read 1st row (DF.row1) and 1st column (DF.Date)
# and use those to set col.names= and skip=

DF.row1 <- read.table(fn, header = TRUE, nrow = 1)
nc <- ncol(DF.row1)
DF.Date <- read.table(fn, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE, 
   colClasses = c(NA, rep("NULL", nc - 1)))
n1985 <- which.max(DF.Date$Date >= "1985-01-01")

DF3 <- read.table(fn, col.names = names(DF.row1), skip = n1985, as.is = TRUE)
```

**sqldf**

```
# this is probably the easiest if data set is large.

library(sqldf)
DF4 <- read.csv.sql(fn, sql = 'select * from file where Date >= "1985-01-01"')
```

Comment: How would you pass multiple arguments to the Date? I.e., if you wanted to return all rows where Date = "2007-01-01" OR "2007-01-02".

Comment: `subset(DF2, Date == "2007-01-01" | Date == "2007-01-02")`

Comment: `where Date = "2007-01-01" or Date = "2007-01-02"`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I am working in Mac. I have ASCII files. I read them into a table called `fl1` as I couldn't load raster pkg yet. It throws me an error at `file` in the sql statement. The code is `specific rows <- read.csv.sql(fl1, sql = 'select * from file where V1 IN (101, 201, 301)`

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` method which will offer speed and memory performance:

```
library(data.table)
fread(file, skip = 1825)
```