# Is there a built-in function for sampling a large delimited data set?

Tags: r

I have a few large data files I'd like to sample when loading into R.  I *can* load the entire data set, but it's really too large to work with.  `sample` does roughly the right thing, but I'd like to have to take random samples of the input while reading it.

I can imagine how to build that with a loop and readline and what-not but surely this has been done hundreds of times.

Is there something in CRAN or even base that can do this?

Comment: See [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Efficiently-reading-random-lines-form-a-large-file-td825269.html) for some ideas.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that in one line of code using sqldf.   See part 6e of [example 6](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf/#Example_6._File_Input) on the [sqldf home page](http://code.google.com/p/sqldf).

Comment: sqldf looks pretty good, but not exactly what I was looking for.  I think it might be the right thing in the long term, though.

Comment: Should the example be added into the answer to make it so that it's not basically a link only answer?

Answer (score 2):

No pre-built facilities. Best approach would be to use a database management program. (Seems as though this was addressed in either SO or Rhelp in the last week.)

Take a look at: [Read csv from specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592219/read-csv-from-specific-row) , and especially note Grothendieck's comments. I consider him a "class A wizaRd". He's got first hand experience with sqldf. (The author IIRC.)

And another "huge files" problem with a Grothendieck solution that succeeded:
[R: how to rbind two huge data-frames without running out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761073/r-how-to-rbind-two-huge-data-frames-without-running-out-of-memory)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following function that does *close* to what I want:

```
readBigBz2 <- function(fn, sample_size=1000) {
    f <- bzfile(fn, "r")
    rv <- c()
    repeat {
        lines <- readLines(f, sample_size)
        if (length(lines) == 0) break
        rv <- append(rv, sample(lines, 1))
    }
    close(f)
    rv
}
```

I may want to go with sqldf in the long-term, but this is a pretty efficient way of sampling the file itself.  I just don't quite know how to wrap that around a connection for read.csv or similar.