# reading a specific row of csv file and its following transformation

Tags: r

For the following ways of reading a csv file using R

```
cd1<-as.character(as.matrix(read.csv('traindata.csv',skip=2,nrows = 1,head=F)))
```

Is this the only way to read a specific row? Moreover, why we have to call `as.matrix` first before calling `as.characte`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read csv from specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592219/read-csv-from-specific-row)

Comment: Thanks, for my second question on as.character(as.matrix, why do we need as.matrix first?

Comment: Hard to say with seeing the data, but you generally don't want to convert a row of a dataframe into a character vector because the columns of the data frame may contain different object types (for example, character and numeric).

Comment: @bbspring,thanks, so as.matrix works to unify the object type, is my understanding right?